# AppCenter upload test fails - android.jar not found

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I've been trying to publish a `Xamarin.Android` test to the **Visual Studio App Center**, using the command line console commands, but it throws the following error:

```
failed to execute: C:\...android.jar not found
```

The **android.jar** referenced is in the Android SDK platform-tools version 26 folder. The file definitely exists, and there are no file locks etc.

This has been happening since I installed the Android version 26 SDK. Before that, I was able to get the process to work.

Is this an issue with Android SDK version 26, or perhaps a compatibility issue with AppCenter?

**Workaround:** If I copy the file android.jar from the Android version 25 platform-tools folder to override the one within the version 26 folder, then the process works.

Comment: If you haven't already, please could you add this as an issue to the appcenter-cli repo on github? I think this is the second instance of this error I've seen.